# EntityFramework: one to many relationship without foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I've got a problem with mapping relations in existing database.

I have two tables:

- `table1`

  - `table1Id` (*primary key*)
  - `table1Code`
  - `table1Field`
- `table2`

  - `table2Id` (*primary key*)
  - `table1Code`
  - `table2Field`

And I've a one-to-many relation between `table2` and `table1`. So I need in `table2` object `table2.table1` which will be filled by looking for `table1` row in `table1` by `table1Code`. Of course I need `ICollection<table2>` inside `table1`.

There is reference in database:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_table2_table1]
    FOREIGN KEY([table1Code]) REFERENCES table1 ([table1Code])
```

I use [EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator) which generates mapping below:

```
HasRequired(a => a.table1)
    .WithMany(b => b.table2)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.table1Code);
```

And when I try to use it I see that generated SQL code compares `table1Id` with `table1Code` (I think that it's because of  `table1Id` as foreign key usage.)

Is it possible to create such mapping between those two tables, which are connected by `table1Code`?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Please provide your entities (models) and whole entity configuration for better understanding.

Comment: You can't do non-key relationships in EF6. EF Core has that feature I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037798/entity-framework-6-1-3-mapping-foreign-key-to-non-primary-key

Comment: Thanks Steve. As I see I have to start learning EntityFramework Core.